# \searrow not long enough!

Tags: arrows

[image: This what I want to write]

I want to write `\searrow` in side array but the length is small and I couldn't make it long.
How I can increase the length of it?

The code is:

```
\[\begin{array}{cccccc}
\phi^{-1}(D)    & R & \!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\hspace*{0.1cm}\phi/R\hspace*{0.1cm}}  & \!\!\!\!D & \cong R/I\\
{\begin{tabular} b\\ \downarrow \\b\end{tabular}} & \Bigg\downarrow{i_2} & \searrow & \Bigg\downarrow{i_1}& {\begin{tabular} \alpha\\ \downarrow \\\alpha\end{tabular}}\\
     & T & \!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\hspace*{0.3cm}\phi\hspace*{0.3cm}} & \!\!\!\!T/I  &
\end{array}\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to recommend tikzcd for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

% \[\begin{array}{cccccc}
% \phi^{-1}(D)    & R & \!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\hspace*{0.1cm}\phi/R\hspace*{0.1cm}}  & \!\!\!\!D & \cong R/I\\
% {\begin{array}{c} b\\ \downarrow \\b\end{array}} & \Bigg\downarrow{i_2} & 
% \searrow & \Bigg\downarrow{i_1}& {\begin{array}{c} \alpha\\ \downarrow
% \\\alpha\end{array}}\\
%      & T & \!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\hspace*{0.3cm}\phi\hspace*{0.3cm}} & \!\!\!\!T/I  &
% \end{array}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2pt,column sep={7mm,between origins}]
\phi^{-1}(D)    & R\arrow[dddd,"i_1"] \arrow[ddddrrr]  \arrow[rrr,"\phi/R"] & &  & D\arrow[dddd,"i_2"] & \cong R/I\\
a\arrow[dd]    &  & &  &  & b\arrow[dd]\\
    &  & &  &  & \\[4mm]
a    &  & &  &  & b\\
    & T \arrow[rrr,"\phi"]& &  & T/I & \\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(You can also find a version of your code which is commented out and which no longer throws errors because I added the column specfier to your tabulars, which I converted to arrays.)

Comment: Thank you so much. It's worked. this's the first time I see this way and It's really great information that I should remember. Thanks again.